# bootstrap new row 11 columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a responsive layout in Bootstrap with vertical aligned columns. The reason is that I want to have several buttons of different sizes in a responsible toolbar.
Searching for ways to do it, the one that seem to work better for me is something like this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYpqLQ

For some reason, this custom styling "float:none" seems to be making bootstrap break into a new row at 11 columns instead of 12. Why could this be?

Thanks!

```
.verti-align  {
    border: solid 1px blue;
}

.verti-align > [class^="col-"],
.verti-align > [class*=" col-"] {
    display: inline-block !important;
    border: solid 1px red;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}
```

---

```
<div class="row verti-align">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">.col-md-3<br><br></div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-3">.col-md-3</div>
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">.col-md-3<br><br></div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-3">.col-md-3 change it to 2 and it works</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use rows?

Comment: do you mean table rows? I tried something like that before but it didn't work for me. I want everything that is on the same line to be vertically aligned but also to be able to break into two rows if the size of the view is small enough.

Comment: Nope, I mean bootstrap rows.

Comment: if I didn't make any mistakes, I'm using bootstrap rows in the code

Comment: Can you upload an image of the normal and mobile view? of what you would like it to look like?

Comment: No problem, it would be something like these:
http://i.imgur.com/a4BoPrW.gif
http://i.imgur.com/RKdPq9V.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add font-size:0 on parent div (.row) and add the font-size you want on children (.col-)

```
 .verti-align  {
        border: solid 1px blue;
        font-size:0;
  }

.verti-align > [class^="col-"],
.verti-align > [class*=" col-"] {
    display: inline-block !important;
    border: solid 1px red;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
    font-size:15px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
That made it work. Could you please tell me why does it need this change?

Comment: display:inline-block creates a most of times undesiblable margin (you can not have margin between bootstrap cols). This above is one of the solutions for "removing" this margin.